# Is it safe to use _byteswap_ulong function as an alternative for __builtin_bswap32?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to safely use _byteswap_ulong function as an alternative for __builtin_bswap32, on Microsoft Windows?

_byteswap_ulong function takes an unsigned long as a parameter and returns an unsigned long. According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges) a long variable is 4 bytes in Microsoft Visual c++. But I have heard that according to C++ specification a long should be at least 4 bytes.

So is it possible for a future Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to make a long variable longer than 4 bytes and as a result _byteswap_ulong and __builtin_bswap32  functions to return different values?

Comment: it's very unlikely that MS will change any of their type sizes (except pointers), providing that they didn't even change `long` to 64-bits because it'll break ancient codes from 16-bit era

Comment: I suggest using the right swap for the data you are swapping